# Delete certain type of files when disk usage is below a treshold

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a powershell script that runs everyday as a scheduledjob and deletes any logs over 30 days old. However, I want for the script to also delete these same files if there is less than 5 GB free disk space. Any ideas what would be the best approach to that?

Here's how the script currently looks:

```
Unregister-ScheduledJob -Name LogRotation -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
wevtutil set-log Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational /enabled:true
$T = New-JobTrigger -Daily -At "12:37 PM" -DaysInterval 1  
$O = @{
WakeToRun=$true
StartIfNotIdle=$false
MultipleInstancePolicy="Queue"
}
$SB = Get-ChildItem "C:\Folder\*" -Recurse -Include *.log | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} | Remove-Item
Register-ScheduledJob -Trigger $T -ScheduledJobOption $O -Name CTLogRotation -ScriptBlock {$SB}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! What have you tried? How are you going to trigger the job to run? Can you schedule the something to watch the disk usage and trigger the job?

Comment: Maybe just running the solution you already have more often (every hour?) would be good enough?  Actually, that doesn't make sense since it is deleting based on age which wouldn't change much throughout the day really.  Also setting a trigger at 5GB doesn't make sense as what would it delete that hasn't already been deleted by the already scheduled daily task?

Comment: Okay, please, allow me to clarify:

The script runs as a scheduled job everyday at 12 on numerous machines and for the most part it works, however, sometimes it is possible that there would be an enormous amount of logs during a period of 2-3-4 days and the disk would get full so I want this to be an extra step to ensure that the logs would get deleted even if they are not 30 days old. so what i want to do is to add a while loop which would delete any .log file in a certain directory if the disk space gets below a certain threshold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first check the remaining disk space. Then create a different scriptblock when that free space is less than 5Gb

```
if (((Get-Volume -DriveLetter C).SizeRemaining / 1Gb) -lt 5) {
    # delete all log files if the remaining size in GB is less than 5
    $SB = Get-ChildItem "C:\Folder" -Recurse -Filter '*.log' -File | Remove-Item -Force
}
else {
    # delete all log files older than 30 days
    $SB = Get-ChildItem "C:\Folder" -Recurse -Filter '*.log' -File | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).Date)} | Remove-Item -Force
}
```

P.S. I'm using `-Filter '*.log'`, because that is way faster than `-Include`.
`-Filter` can however have just one file pattern.
I also added switch `-File`, so the code does not look for directories